# Mapping / Looping inside dumb component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, reusability, react-component

I create a dumb component that used by so many data, but same display.

The problem is, is it better dumb component to accept only native data type or array of object? since my data property is difference each table.

```
<ScrollView>
  {listOfData.map(()=>(
    <Dumb title={data.title} description={data.description} >
  ))}
</ScrollView>
```

pros: No object properties dependancy

cons: Need Loop in smart component which make it messy
**vs**

```
<ScrollView>
    <Dumbs data={listOfData} >
</ScrollView>
```

pros: More simple in smart component

cons: The dumb component only accept specific data properties

So which one better? I do use a second one and mapping it in my component.ts first to change object properties, but it make component.ts messy

Answer (score 1):

I think the nicest way would be:

```
<ScrollView>
    {listOfData.map((data) => (
        <Dumb key={data.id} {...data} />
    ))}
</ScrollView>
```

**data.id must be anything unique for each item.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first method as it makes the component more reusable in case if your `listOfData` has different structure for some other `data-source` then you would need to check and extract the **title** and **description** for different data structure.

```
<ScrollView>
    {listOfData.map((data) => (
        <Dumb key={data.id} description={data.desc} title={data.title} />
    ))}
</ScrollView>
```